# How to insert multiple dataset into multiple tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a beginner for Codeigniter. I'm currently creating a registration page. I want to enter data into 4 tables at once using CodeIgniter. the table is tbl_asesi, tbl_pdd_non_formal, tbl_work, tbl_organization, but new data comes in 1 table, namely tbl_asesi while the other tables are still empty. can you help me fix the code?

The controller that I use is as follows

my controller :

```
<?PHP
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pendaftaran extends CI_Controller {

  public function index()
  {

    $data = array(

      'bidang' => $this->m_pendaftaran->get_bidang(),
      'subbidang' => $this->m_pendaftaran->get_subbidang(),
      'jenis_bidang' => $this->m_pendaftaran->get_jenis_bidang(),
      'level' => $this->m_pendaftaran->get_level(),
      'okupasi' => $this->m_pendaftaran->get_okupasi(),
      'unitinti' => $this->m_pendaftaran->get_unitinti(),
      'unitpilihan1' => $this->m_pendaftaran->get_unitpilihan1(),
      'unitpilihan2' => $this->m_pendaftaran->get_unitpilihan2(),
      'unitpilihan3' => $this->m_pendaftaran->get_unitpilihan3(),
      'bidang_selected' => '',
      'subbidang_selected' => '',
      'jenis_bidang_selected' => '',
      'level_selected' => '',
      'okupasi_selected' => '',
      'unitinti_selected' => '',
      'unitpilihan1_selected' => '',
      'unitpilihan2_selected' => '',
      'unitpilihan3_selected' => '',
    );

    $this->template->load('static','pendaftaran',$data);

  }

  function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
       $this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
       $this->load->model('m_pendaftaran');
       $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

     }

     public function daftarasesi() {

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'NAMA','required'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('nik', 'NIK','required'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('jenis_kelamin', 'JENIS_KELAMIN','required'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat', 'ALAMAT','required');   
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('jabatan', 'JABATAN','');      
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('asal_institusi', 'ASAL_INSTITUSI','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat_institusi', 'ALAMAT_INSTITUSI','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_hp', 'NO_HP','required');  
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','EMAIL','required|valid_email');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('sd', 'SD','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('kota_sd', 'KOTA_SD','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_sd', 'TAHUN_SD','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('smp', 'SMP','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('kota_smp', 'KOTA_SMP','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_smp', 'TAHUN_SMP','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('sma', 'SMA','required');    
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('kota_sma', 'KOTA_SMA','required'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_sma', 'TAHUN_SMA','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('d', 'D');    
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('kota_d', 'KOTA_D'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_d', 'TAHUN_D');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('s1', 'S1');    
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('kota_s1', 'KOTA_S1'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_s1', 'TAHUN_S1');  
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('s2', 'S2');    
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('kota_s2', 'KOTA_S2'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_s2', 'TAHUN_S2');     
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('s3', 'S3');    
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('kota_s3', 'KOTA_S3'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_s3', 'TAHUN_S3'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('pelatihan', 'PELATIHAN');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('lembaga', 'LEMBAGA');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('kota_pelatihan', 'KOTA_PELATIHAN');   
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_pelatihan', 'TAHUN_PELATIHAN'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('kegiatan', 'KEGIATAN'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('institusi', 'INSTITUSI'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_kerja', 'TAHUN_KERJA'); 
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_organisasi', 'NAMA ORGANISASI');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('status_anggota', 'STATUS ANGGOTA');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('surat_organisasi', 'SURAT ORGANISASI');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun_organisasi', 'TAHUN_ORGANISASI');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('bidang', 'BIDANG','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('subbidang', 'SUBBIDANG','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('level', 'LEVEL','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('jenis_bidang', 'JENIS_BIDANG','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('okupasi', 'OKUPASI','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('unitinti', 'UNITINTI','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('unitpilihan1', 'UNITPILIHAN1','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('unitpilihan2', 'UNITPILIHAN2','');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('unitpilihan3', 'UNITPILIHAN3',''); 

      if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('gagaldaftar', 'Maaf, Pendaftaran Gagal Dilakukan.');
        $this->template->load('static','pendaftaran');
      }else{

        $data_asesi['nama']             =    $this->input->post('nama');  
        $data_asesi['nik']              =    $this->input->post('nik');   
        $data_asesi['jenis_kelamin']    =    $this->input->post('jenis_kelamin');  
        $data_asesi['alamat']           =    $this->input->post('alamat');  
        $data_asesi['jabatan']          =    $this->input->post('jabatan');
        $data_asesi['asal_institusi']   =    $this->input->post('asal_institusi');
        $data_asesi['alamat_institusi'] =    $this->input->post('alamat_institusi');
        $data_asesi['no_hp']            =    $this->input->post('no_hp');           
        $data_asesi['email']            =    $this->input->post('email');
        $data_asesi['sd']               =    $this->input->post('sd');
        $data_asesi['kota_sd']          =    $this->input->post('kota_sd');
        $data_asesi['tahun_sd']         =    $this->input->post('tahun_sd');
        $data_asesi['smp']              =    $this->input->post('smp');
        $data_asesi['kota_smp']         =    $this->input->post('kota_smp');
        $data_asesi['tahun_smp']        =    $this->input->post('tahun_smp');
        $data_asesi['sma']              =    $this->input->post('sma'); 
        $data_asesi['kota_sma']         =    $this->input->post('kota_sma');
        $data_asesi['tahun_sma']        =    $this->input->post('tahun_sma'); 
        $data_asesi['d']                =    $this->input->post('d'); 
        $data_asesi['kota_d']           =    $this->input->post('kota_d');
        $data_asesi['tahun_d']          =    $this->input->post('tahun_d');      
        $data_asesi['s1']               =    $this->input->post('s1'); 
        $data_asesi['kota_s1']          =    $this->input->post('kota_s1');
        $data_asesi['tahun_s1']         =    $this->input->post('tahun_s1'); 
        $data_asesi['s2']               =    $this->input->post('s2'); 
        $data_asesi['kota_s2']          =    $this->input->post('kota_s2');
        $data_asesi['tahun_s2']         =    $this->input->post('tahun_s2'); 
        $data_asesi['s3']               =    $this->input->post('s3'); 
        $data_asesi['kota_s3']          =    $this->input->post('kota_s3');
        $data_asesi['tahun_s3']         =    $this->input->post('tahun_s3'); 

        //tabel tbl_pdd_non_formal
        $data_non_formal = array();
        $data_non_formal['pelatihan']        =    $this->input->post('pelatihan');
        $data_non_formal['lembaga']          =    $this->input->post('lembaga');
        $data_non_formal['kota_pelatihan']   =    $this->input->post('kota_pelatihan');
        $data_non_formal['tahun_pelatihan']  =    $this->input->post('tahun_pelatihan');

        //tabel tbl_pekerjaan
        $data_pekerjaan = array();
        $data_pekerjaan['kegiatan']         =    $this->input->post('kegiatan');
        $data_pekerjaan['institusi']        =    $this->input->post('institusi');
        $data_pekerjaan['surat_pendukung']  =    $this->input->post('surat_pendukung');
        $data_pekerjaan['tahun_kerja']      =    $this->input->post('tahun_kerja');

        //tbl_organisasi
        $data_organisasi = array();
        $data_organisasi['nama_organisasi']  =    $this->input->post('nama_organisasi');
        $data_organisasi['status_anggota']   =    $this->input->post('status_anggota');
        $data_organisasi['surat_organisasi'] =    $this->input->post('surat_organisasi');
        $data_organisasi['tahun_organisasi'] =    $this->input->post('tahun_organisasi');

        //tbl_asesi
        $data_asesi['bidang']           =    $this->input->post('bidang'); 
        $data_asesi['subbidang']        =    $this->input->post('subbidang'); 
        $data_asesi['level']            =    $this->input->post('level');
        $data_asesi['jenis_bidang']     =    $this->input->post('jenis_bidang');  
        $data_asesi['okupasi']          =    $this->input->post('okupasi'); 
        $data_asesi['unitinti']         =    $this->input->post('unitinti'); 
        $data_asesi['unitpilihan1']     =    $this->input->post('unitpilihan1'); 
        $data_asesi['unitpilihan2']     =    $this->input->post('unitpilihan2'); 
        $data_asesi['unitpilihan3']     =    $this->input->post('unitpilihan3');

        // var_dump($data_asesi);
        // var_dump($data_non_formal);
        // var_dump($data_pekerjaan);
        // var_dump($data_organisasi);

        $this->m_pendaftaran->daftarasesi($data_asesi, $data_non_formal, $data_pekerjaan, $data_organisasi);

        // $this->m_pendaftaran->daftarasesi($data); 

        $this->session->set_flashdata('berhasil', 'Pendaftaran Berhasil Dilakukan.');         
        $this->template->load('static','pendaftaran');
      }
    }          

    public function lakukan_download_asesi(){       
    force_download('berkas/berkas_asesi.rar',NULL);
   }

 }
```

the model that I use is as follows

my model :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_pendaftaran extends CI_Model 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function daftarasesi($asesi, $non_formal, $pekerjaan, $organisasi)
    { 
        // insert data asesi //
        $this->db->insert('tbl_asesi',$asesi);
        $nik_fk = $this->db->insert_nik();

        // insert data non formal //
        $data_non_formal['nik_fk'] = $nik_fk;
        $this->db->insert('tbl_pdd_non_formal',$non_formal);
        return $insert_nik = $this->db->insert_nik();

        // insert data pekerjaan //
        $data_pekerjaan['nik_fk'] = $nik_fk;
        $this->db->insert('tbl_pekerjaan',$pekerjaan);
        return $insert_nik = $this->db->insert_nik();

         // insert data organisasi //
        $data_organisasi['nik_fk'] = $nik_fk;
        $this->db->insert('tbl_organisasi',$organisasi);
        return $insert_nik = $this->db->insert_nik();
    }
```

Comment: i guess you have to be a bit more specific - but the things i see: `$this->db->insert_nik()` isn't a known function in Codeigniter and you hsould remove the first two `return` statements in your model function `daftarasesi` - and to avoid your update/insert issue you have to send the corresponding id from your html form.

Comment: I will enter data with the primary key in the nik column. I therefore use $this->db->insert_nik(). Are there other solutions to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing wrong and in Codeigniter there is no query builder function exists called `$this->db->insert_nik()` and you were returning this, so it was not working. So you shouldn't use this.

You can insert data into multiple tables from one form as following way and Use this in your model.

```
public function daftarasesi($asesi, $non_formal, $pekerjaan, $organisasi)
{ 
    $this->db->trans_start();

    // insert data asesi //
    $this->db->insert('tbl_asesi',$asesi);

    // insert data non formal //
    $this->db->insert('tbl_pdd_non_formal',$non_formal);

    // insert data pekerjaan //
    $this->db->insert('tbl_pekerjaan',$pekerjaan);

    // insert data pekerjaan //
    $this->db->insert('tbl_pekerjaan',$pekerjaan);

    // insert data organisasi //
    $this->db->insert('tbl_organisasi',$organisasi);

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        return FALSE;

    } else {

        $this->db->trans_commit();
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

> You can run as many queries as you want between the start/complete
>   functions and they will all be committed or rolled back based on
>   success or failure of any given query.
>
> **N.B:** Always use transaction when you're dealing with multiple insertion/updation.

Comment: I tried to do it, but the result is still an error. and the error lies in the models when inserting data_non_formal etc. are there any other solutions?